# Multipe If conditions not working in JMeter IF controller

Tags: jmeter

I need to execute specific api only for dedicated users from CsvTestconfig file
Test1
Test2
Test3
Test4
...
Test40

For example:
API1 to be executed only by users (Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4)
I have used below code in JMeter IF condition.
but it is not working as expected. for single condition it works fine.

${__javaScript("${LOGINUSER}" == "Test1" || "${LOGINUSER}" == "Test2" || "${LOGINUSER}" == "Test3" || "${LOGINUSER}" == "Test4")}

API2 should be executed by all other users except users (Test20, Test22, Test30)

${__javaScript("${LOGINUSER}" != "Test20" || "${LOGINUSER}" != "Test22" || "${LOGINUSER}" != "Test30")}

Appreciate if anyone can help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use `__jexl3` or `__groovy` as suggested and `vars.get` is recommended to fetch variables
[image]

Comment: Hi  Any help on how we can handle this  API2 should be executed by all other users except users (Test20, Test22, Test30)

${__javaScript("${LOGINUSER}" != "Test20" || "${LOGINUSER}" != "Test22" || "${LOGINUSER}" != "Test30")}

Comment: I have tried below snippet in IF controller, this is not working as expected.

${__groovy(vars.get("LOGINUSER") != "Test20" || vars.get("LOGINUSER") != "Test22")} 

Can we use an in operation like this ?
${__groovy(vars.get("LOGINUSER") in ["Test20", "Test22"])

Comment: you are right. the OR condition is causing issues

Comment: How about this one

`${__groovy(!(vars.get("LOGINUSER") == "Test5" || vars.get("LOGINUSER") == "Test6" || vars.get("LOGINUSER") == "Test7" || vars.get("LOGINUSER") == "Test8"))}`

Comment: Appreciate if any one can help on this.

Comment: Hi Rahul,  Thanks for your help. above shared snippet works